# How to measure a correlated operator $Z_1Z_2$?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, measurement, linear-algebra

I was reading [this articl](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.04890) and I am stuck trying to understand equation $(60)$, which reads

$$\langle\psi|\Lambda_{1,2}(X)Z_1\Lambda_{1,2}(X)|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|Z_1Z_2|\psi\rangle$$ where $\Lambda(X)=|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes X$ defines the CNOT gate.

How do we obtain this equation?

Also, I do not understand what does $Z_i$ mean for $i=1,2$ and what the subscripts $_{1,2}$ in $\Lambda_{1,2}$ are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Subscripts

The meaning of the subscripts is explained in the preceding sentence

> Still the expectation value of the single qubit
> operator $Z_k$ on the $k$th qubit is [...]

i.e. the subscript refers to the qubit on which the operator acts. Also, even though this does not appear to be stated explicitly, one would usually read the subscripts on $\Lambda_{1,2}$ as referring to the control and target qubits, respectively. This is suggested by the expression

$$\Lambda(X)=|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes X$$

which flips the second qubit if the first qubit is $|1\rangle$.

### Measuring $Z_1Z_2$

Under this interpretation of $\Lambda_{1,2}$, the equation $(60)$ is wrong, because

$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda_{1,2}(X)Z_1\Lambda_{1,2}(X) &= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)Z_1(|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes X) \\
&= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)(Z_1|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I+Z_1|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes X) \\
&= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)(|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I-|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes X) \\
&= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)(|0\rangle\langle0|Z_1\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle1|Z_1\otimes X) \\
&= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)(|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes X)Z_1 \\
&= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)\Lambda_{1,2}(X)Z_1 \\
&= Z_1.
\end{align}
$$

On the other hand,

$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda_{1,2}(X)Z_2\Lambda_{1,2}(X) &= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)Z_2(|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes X) \\
&= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)(|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes Z_2+|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes Z_2X) \\
&= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)(|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes Z_2-|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes XZ_2) \\
&= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)(|0\rangle\langle0|Z_1\otimes Z_2+|1\rangle\langle1|Z_1\otimes XZ_2) \\
&= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)(|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes X)(Z_1\otimes Z_2) \\
&= \Lambda_{1,2}(X)\Lambda_{1,2}(X)Z_1Z_2 \\
&= Z_1Z_2.
\end{align}
$$

There are two ways to interpret the above. Either there is a mistake in the paper and the equation $(60)$ should read

$$
\langle\psi|\Lambda_{1,2}(X)Z_\color{red}{2}\Lambda_{1,2}(X)|\psi\rangle = \langle\psi|Z_1Z_2|\psi\rangle
$$

or $\Lambda_{1,2}$ actually refers to the CNOT gate with qubit $1$ as the target and qubit $2$ as the control. Personally, I find the former much more likely.

In any case, the error is very minor and has no effect on any claims in the paper. In particular, it is true that entangling operations like $\Lambda_{1,2}(X)$ enable one to measure correlated operators like $Z_1Z_2$.